# Printing perforated business cards

Tags: printer, paper

I have a Brother MFC 440CN printer with the paper loaded underneath it. The problem with my stack of perforated business cards is that I can't print double-sided.

The printer pulls the paper out from under its paper tray below and rolls it through the top for printing. With perforated business cards, they paper breaks at the perforations. Is there a method to preventing the slicing?

Also, my printer also has some trouble pulling up the paper in general but I don't seem to understand why other than that the perforations break before the paper is grabbed for printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using the manual feed (tray 1), since this minimizes the bending the paper goes through. There's probably a door or flap on the front that you can open to feed paper directly.

Answer (score 0):

Many printers provide a straight paper path, which prevents curling and similar problems. The Brother 440CN unfortunately does not, which means that there is no way to solve your problem short of using another printer model.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to get the paper in at all? My printer seems to have a lot of trouble curling in it for printing.